# ASP.NET Core. Get value from a Select tag without JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to call a specific Action with a parameter that corresponds to the the selected element in a  tag.

The Model of the View can be simplified as follows:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string SelectedElement {get; set}
    public List<SelectListItem> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

That i'm trying to display in the View:

```html
<h2>Info</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="selector-info" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Elements</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select id="selector-info" asp-for="@Model.SelectedElement " asp-items="@Model.Elements">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary"
           asp-controller="Info"
           asp-action="Export"
           asp-route-element="@Model.SelectedElement ">
            Exportar
        </a>
</div>
```

And the action in the controller:

```cs
[Route("export/{element}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Export(string element)
        {
            // Do something with the data


            return RedirectToAction("Info");
        }
```

Here what I'm trying to do is to call this specific Action that accepts a parameter, and fill it with the selcted element in the  tag

But the generated HTML href was incorrect, and debugging I found out that the value `Model.SelectedElement` was not beeing set correctly.

On the other hand if I wrap this code inside a form and change the link to a button it works. My problem with this is that I'll have multiple buttons (at least 2) that will do different actions but in all cases the selected value of the  tag must be passed when the button is clicked.

Is there a way to achieve this? I know I can get the value through JavaScript but I'm trying to find a way to do this directly in ASP without JS.

Comment: ASP, ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are very different. Please select one.

Comment: It's ASP.NET Core

Comment: You can assign different actions to each button even within the same form - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit , specifically the "formaction" attribute